# vue.js - редактирование динамического списка. Как правильно сделать отмену редактирования?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

Всем привет. Пишу код на вью, который работает со списком. 
Я могу добавлять, удалять, редактировать элементы, и выводить их на страницу.

Проблема в редактировании: по задумке, во время редактирования, если нажать отмену, то текст вернется в обратный вид.

Пример ниже

Начальный текст: "Привет, мой "
Редактируем: "Привет, друг!" +отмена+
Текст возвращается в изначальный - "Привет, мой ".

Однако на деле. При отмене измененный текст сохраняется. В том числе в объект...

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          newPic: '',
            //start:0,
            //tasks:[{text: "task1", mode:"task"}, {text: "task2", mode:"task"}]
            images: [{src: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png', 
            editable: false}, 
            {src: 'https://iconscout.com/iconscout_logo-1024x1024.png',editable: false}],
            end:10,
            editableImageTemp: null
        },
        methods: {
         addElement: function(source){
           this.images.push({src: source, editable: false});
            console.log(this.images);
            
          },
         deleteElement: function(index) {
            this.images.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(this.images);
          },
          enableEditing: function(index) {
            this.editableImageTemp = this.images[index];
            this.images[index].editable=true;
            console.log(this.images);
            console.log(this.editableImageTemp);
          },
          disableEditing: function(index){
            this.editableImageTemp = null;
            this.images[index].editable=false;
            console.log(this.images[index].src);
            console.log(this.editableImageTemp);
       },
          saveEdit: function(index){
            // However we want to save it to the database
            //alert(this.images[index].src);
           this.images[index] = this.editableImageTemp;
           this.disableEditing(index);
          }
        },
        computed:{
            visibleList: function(){
                return this.images.slice(this.start,this.end);
            },
            imgSrcLength: function() {
             return this.images.length;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    Слотов с картинками добавлено: {{ imgSrcLength }}
    <p><input type="text" v-model="newPic" /><button v-on:click="addElement(newPic)">Добавить</button></p>
    <!--<input v-model="start" type="number" /> -->
    <!-- <input v-model="end" type="number" /> -->
    <ul>

    
      <li v-for="(img, index) in visibleList">
        <div v-if="!images[index].editable">        
          {{ index + 1}}.<span class='text'>{{ img.src }}</span> 
          <button type="button" v-on:click="enableEditing(index)">✎</button>
          <button type="button" v-on:click="deleteElement(index)">❌</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="images[index].editable">
           <input v-model=editableImageTemp.src class="input" size="70px"/>
           <button v-on:click="saveEdit(index)"></button>
           <button v-on:click="disableEditing(index)">⊗</button>
        </div>
      </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/nr46g520/202/)

Очень прошу помочь. Глаз замылился, никак не пойму, почему не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему путем неполного сохранения объекта в editableImageTemp.
Теперь сохранил только свойство src, которое мне и нужно.

[Решение в JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/nr46g520/211/)

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          newPic: '',
            //start:0,
            //tasks:[{text: "task1", mode:"task"}, {text: "task2", mode:"task"}]
            images: [{src: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png', 
            editable: false}, 
            {src: 'https://iconscout.com/iconscout_logo-1024x1024.png',editable: false}],
            end:10,
            editableImageTemp: null
        },
        methods: {
         addElement: function(source){
           this.images.push({src: source, editable: false});
            console.log(this.images);
            
          },
         deleteElement: function(index) {
            this.images.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(this.images);
          },
          enableEditing: function(index) {
            this.editableImageTemp = this.images[index].src;
            this.images[index].editable=true;
            console.log(this.images);
            console.log(this.editableImageTemp);
          },
          disableEditing: function(index){
            this.editableImageTemp = null;
            this.images[index].editable=false;
            console.log(this.images[index].src);
            console.log(this.editableImageTemp);
       },
          saveEdit: function(index){
            // However we want to save it to the database
            //alert(this.images[index].src);
           this.images[index].src = this.editableImageTemp;
           this.disableEditing(index);
          }
        },
        computed:{
            visibleList: function(){
                return this.images.slice(this.start,this.end);
            },
            imgSrcLength: function() {
             return this.images.length;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    Слотов с картинками добавлено: {{ imgSrcLength }}
    <p><input type="text" v-model="newPic" /><button v-on:click="addElement(newPic)">Добавить</button></p>
    <!--<input v-model="start" type="number" /> -->
    <!-- <input v-model="end" type="number" /> -->
    <ul>  
      <li v-for="(img, index) in visibleList">
        <div v-if="!images[index].editable">   
          {{ index + 1}}.<span class='text'>{{ images[index].src }}</span> 
          <button type="button" v-on:click="enableEditing(index)">✎</button>
          <button type="button" v-on:click="deleteElement(index)">❌</button><br>
          <img v-bind:src="images[index].src" width="700" height="auto" alt="" >
        </div>
        <div v-if="images[index].editable">
           <input v-model="editableImageTemp" class="input" size="70px"/>
           <button v-on:click="saveEdit(index)"></button>
           <button v-on:click="disableEditing(index)">⊗</button>
        </div>
      </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Объекты передаются по ссылке, вам нужно добавить временную переменную, которая хранила бы изначальные значения:

```
tmp: {}, //в data
enableEditing: function(index) {
    Object.assign(this.tmp, this.images[index]);

    this.editableImageTemp = this.images[index];
    this.images[index].editable=true;
    console.log(this.images);
    console.log(this.editableImageTemp);
},
```

а потом восстановить данные назад

```
disableEditing: function(index){
    this.editableImageTemp = null;

    Object.assign(this.images[index], this.tmp);

    this.images[index].editable=false;
    console.log(this.images[index].src);
    console.log(this.editableImageTemp);
},
```

Пример схематичный, не работал с Vue и не знаю как он обзервит массивы и можно ли просто подменять объект в массиве. Поэтому я просто копировал свойства.